# Crystal report output in one row

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show multiple row in one row based on a Time. same this example

Same this :

```
time    type1     type2   type3     type4
1.......2.5.......3.......2.5.......0
2.......2.........2.......0.........0
3.......3.........0.......0.........0
4.......1.9.......0.......0.........0
5.......2.........0.......0.........0
6.......2.1.......0.......0.........0
```

This my record table below:

```
time    type    value
1       1       2.5
1       2       3
1       3       2.5
2       1       2
2       2       2
3       1       2
4       1       1.9
5       1       2
6       1       2.1
```

I insert formula field for each field had this code

```
if ({type}=1) then
{value}
```

I get this row had 0 and other row had the real value.

[image: that what i have !]

Comment: You can use cross tab to achieve the desire result

Comment: Sorry to delay reply to your answer .. i tried the "cross-tab" but not same what i need, also it have empty line between rows